# Data mapping optimization: X database queries vs. Y Java if statements

Tags: java, sql, performance

Currently we retrieve a List of objects from the Spring SimpleJdbcTemplate.  The first query is a select * to retrieve all records that we will want to be our "keys" .  This then leads to a foreach loop over the collection which in turn involves N queries back to the database where N is the size of the List.  Would it be more efficient to do these N queries or do 2 large select * statements and map them through a for loop that does an if statement?  See code below:

```
N Queries  

List keyList = Select * from keyTable;
for(Object o: keyList)  
   {  
      List valueList = Select * from valueTable;  
      //Map valueTable to keyTable via rowmapper  
    }  




Y Java if statements  
    List keyList = Select * from keyTable;  
    List valueList = Select * from valueTable;  
    for(Object o: keyList)  
       {   
           for(Object z : valueList)  
             {    
                  if(z.key == o.key)  //set the value  
             }   
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a java programmer, but wouldn't it be simpler to have the database perform the join, since most modern database engines are designed and built to optimize the join process? Guessing at the syntax, you'd have the query

```
Select * from keyTable o
 inner join valueTable z
  on o.key = z.key
```

somehow within your code, perhaps like so:

```
List keyValueList = select * from keyTable o inner join valueTable z on o.key = z.key;
```

Comment: Without testing the code I suppose that is one way to do it.  The issue seems to be that we eat a lot of time on the invocation of the function because it is reaching out to the database so many times.  I am not sure that the above would fix the problem since there is still an internal mapping that needs to occur.  Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: You definitely want to avoid round-trips between the application and database servers. Your first example has N+1 trips, the second has 2 trips, and my idea has 1. If the round-trips are what's taking all the time, minimize those (and 1 isn't that much better than 2); if processing the data retrieved is what's taking all the time, you'll want to focus on optimizing that.

Comment: Equally true.  I will attempt to implement your solution and see what initial gains I get.  As it stands we are somewhere in the 2+ minute range and it is only 60 entries in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are, in order:

- Let the database do the join. This is *by far* the best option, and there is hardly ever a reason to do otherwise:

```
    select k.key, v.value from keyTable k, valueTable v where k.key=v.key
```

- If for whatever reason you need to do the join at the application level, there is an index on valueTable.key, and you expect few results, do a **nested loops join**:

```
    List keyList = Select key from keyTable;
    for (Object k: keyList) {  
        List valueList = Select value from valueTable where key = k;
        for (Object v: valueList) {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
```

- For the cases not covered by the nested loops join, do a **hash join**:

```
    HashMap keyHash = select key, k.* from keyTable k;
    List valueList = select * from valueType v;
    for (Object k: valueList) {
        if (keyHash.containsKey(k)) {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
```

- Last of all, you can try a **[sort-merge join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort-merge_join)**

Answer (score 0):

you should use a sql join or subquery to retrieve all your data in a single sql statement. this will allow the database to utilize whatever optimizations mechanisms (indexing and execution plans, caching, etc) that might be available.

using sql join:

```
select key,value from keyTable k, valueTable v where k.key=v.key
```

using subquery (only if a key has a unique value):

```
select key, (select value from valueTable where key=k.key) from keyTable k
```